# How to change PHP include when a different link is clicked

Tags: php, html

Just started learning PHP, started using includes so that I don't have to have the same HTML code on different pages and copy past.

Currently I am using:

```
include("pages/header.php")
```

This is taking all my html for my menu and putting it into my `index.php` page. Now I'm wanting to take it a step further and put my content into its own file like `home.php` and `contact.php` then use the include to pull in the html to my `index.php` when those pages have been clicked on in the menu.

Is there a specific method to go about doing this? I probably would need some if statements to check what it needs to include and change, just not sure how to go about it. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Why do you want everything on the same page? Why not just make each page and different includes with all the html?

Comment: If you want a single page application you'll want to look into JavaScript AJAX.

Comment: That is a poor practice. The user will have an easier time using your website if each "page" is actually a separate file. But, you can use the get string to say "index.html?page=home" or "index.html?page=contact" and then use $_GET['page'] to see which file to include.

Comment: @kainaw that is what I was going to do more or less. I was going to make files for my home, contact, portfolio and then use the index.php as the place that exchanges the includes files like you have suggested with the $_GET['page'] not sure if I am on the wrong page here :)

Comment: You are new to PHP so I won't hold it against you to not pick the best answer as best answer :), but I hope you will take one bit of advice from me. If you have repetitive commands (like the 'if/else if' right now) in your code you just know you are doing something wrong. Think of what Tim's code will look like when you have 20 pages to choose from, compare that with my code. Think of what work it will involve in case you want to change something. Stick to the DRY(S) principle when coding (Don't Repeat Yourself (Stupid))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @Tim but would take a slightly different approach on how the page is handled.

```
<a href="index.php?page=about">About</a>


<?php

$allowed = array('about', 'header', 'index'); // add the pagenames you need
$page = ( isset($_GET['page']) ) ? $_GET['page'] : 'index';
if ( in_array($page, $allowed) )
    include("pages/$page.php");
} else {
    include("pages/404.php");
}
?>
```

Whenever you create a new page you only have to add it to the array to make it work. You won't have to create another if/else.

To clarify the code some more.
Your link will provide a value for `page`.
In `$allowed` the valid pagenames are stored. Numbers are confusing, use names.

Then the value of the `$page` variable is set by checking the `$_GET['page']` value.
If a value has been set (which means a link was clicked) it will use that value. If no value is present it will set `$page` to index.

Finally the `if-statement` checks whether or not the given value is present in `$allowed`. If it is it will include that page, if it is not it will include 404.

A benefit from this approach is that it is easily maintained/adjusted when you need to add more pages.

Comment: So with this one it is loading the various pages that it is needed for example the 'About' page id imagine?

Comment: The only question I would have is how do I go about making sure that my index page loads the home page without having to worry about a button being clicked to recognize it?

Comment: It will load the page  requested in the `$_GET` variable, but only if it is present in the `$allowed` variable. This will prevent people from trying to load other pages than the one you intended.

Comment: Okay great will have to play around a bit, to understand it all thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For your links to other pages you're going to need add a variable to them as a reference to the content you want to include. For example:

```
<a href="index.php?page=2">About</a>
```

Then in your PHP where you want to include files you'll have to retrieve the variable and display the corresponding file you want to include. Here's how that would work:

```
<?php
$PageNum = $_GET['page'];
if ($PageNum == 1) {
    include("pages/header.php")
} else if ($PageNum == 2) {
    include("pages/about.php")
} else {
    include("pages/404.php")
}
?>
```

This retrieves the variable we set in our link and includes the corresponding page.

You probably want your index page to show up without any variable set. For example you could have links for 'Contact' with page=1 and 'About' with page=2. When you process $PageNum just do

```
if ($PageNum ==1) {
    include("pages/contact.php") 
} else if ($PageNum ==2) {
    include("pages/about.php") 
} else { 
    include("pages/header.php")
}
```

This way when no variable is set (if they just go to index.php) it will show them the header.php file, otherwise it will show them about or contact.

Comment: Okay great will start looking into this. Is there any reason why $PageNum is set to 1? sorry for ignorance just trying to grasp the thought process

Comment: In the example here $PageNum is retrieving whatever variable is in the link. For example if the user went to index.php, $PageNum would not be set so it would take them to pages/404.php. If they clicked on the 'About' link example I posted it would set $PageNum to 2 and take them to pages/about.php. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Oh wait I see. So the actual links being used in my menu, I am giving a page value to them, so that it understands what it needs to retrieve i would imagine

Comment: Yes, the links need to include the 'page' variable which gets retrieved and put into the $PageNum container which is then used to determine what file to include.

Comment: Would I have to set my index.php page to a page=2 in order for it to load the correct includes?

Comment: You probably want your index page to show up without any variable set. For example you could have links for 'Contact' with page=1 and 'About' with page=2. When you process $PageNum just do If ($PageNum ==1) { include("pages/contact.php") } else if ($PageNum ==2) { include("pages/about.php") } else { include("pages/header.php") }

I'll add that into my post so you can see the formatting.

Comment: awesome will play around with it a little and get a hang of it, thanks!